# Path-style and Node-style Component label attributes

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, circuitikz

I am trying to define the attributes of the label within a specific path-style component. The issue is specifying the attributes within the declaration of the component. See code below.

```
\draw[] (S1.G) to [short, -*, label={[label distance=0.0cm]left:$G_{S1}$}] ($(S1.G) + (-0.5,0)$) coordinate(VgS1);
```

[image]

The same approach is valid when I try to define the same attributes for a node-style component. See example below.

```
\draw[orange]   ($(Lr1 |- s1s) + (2.5,0.1)$) node[currarrow, orange, xscale=-1, label={[label distance=0.0cm]above:$i_1$}] (currdir3) {};
```

[image]

Does the path-style component have a different way of defining the attributes of the label? Or do I have to create a node in that position so that I can follow the same approach as node-style components (as in the example page 226 in the 1.6.0 manual?

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate name for the `circuitikz` label, maybe, but the `circuitikz` label (commands `l`, `l_`, etc.) have nothing to do with the [`label` from Ti*k*Z](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.10) (which is much more powerful). As you have seen, you can't apply a Ti*k*Z label to path (`to[...])` components, although you can apply it to *any* node component.

But I think you are overthinking it:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\node [nigfete, bodydiode](S1){S1};
    \draw[] (S1.G) to [short, -*] ++(-0.5,0) coordinate(VgS1)
        node[left]{$G_{S1}$};
% for the bounding box
    \path (S1) ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rmano .. I must agree with you, I am overthinking over this topic.. my just hope was the syntax would be the same for specifying the labeling attributes! Though, it does not take anything to just add a node next to it and apply the same ! Thanks again for your help..